# Why I'm receiving the 'Connection time out' when I try to run the 'python manage.py migrate' code on putty?

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, putty

Ok, I'm trying to deploy a Django project using EC2 instance

I've already created an RDS/Postgree database and test it through my IDE before deploy it and it's working correctly

But when I try to run the 'python manage.py migrate' code on putty I'm receiving this error

angtradingdb.xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com" (xxxxxxx), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out

I've set 2 inbound rules on my RDS instance:

- First I put PostgreSQL as 'Type', 'TCP' as Protocol, 5432 as 'Port Range' and my IP as 'Source'
- Second inbound rule, it's the same thing but the VPC security group of my EC2 application as 'Source'

I've done that before and those 2 rules where enough for the deployment to work

Any idea of what can be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try a connectivity test from your ec2.
Open the console in your ec2 and try with

```
telnet IP(rds) Port(rds)
```

If in the case exists connection, review the connection configuration in your project.

Comment: Same error "Connection time out"

Comment: I understand that telnet give same error, so your network configuration is wrong. I imagine this scenary, your RDS and EC2 are hosted in same VPC, same subent. You need to setup the security group from RDS with source ip-ec2/32 and port  5432, but if you debug the connection, you can apply in source 0.0.0.0 with port 5432. With those you ensure connectivity from any ec2.

Comment: I solve that by 'Connect to EC2 Instance' option in the RDS sections, it was my first time doing that and it work

Anyway, tks for your help!